# How to save game data in python3 (Pygame) in a txt file?

Tags: python-3.x, string, list

I'm working on a cookie clicker game and I want to save the amount of cookies and cps and other variable in a txt file. I make one line in the txt file a list like this: [100, 0, 0] (Cookes, cps, # of auto clickers etc). However, when I do this to assign the value in the list to the variable, instead of doing say the value '100' is just does the first letter in the thing

```
cookies =]
cps = data[1]
auto_clicker_num = data[2]
```

This code:

```
cookies = 0
cps = 0
auto_clicker_num = 0

with open('data.txt') as data:
    data = data.readlines()[1] #I have it read the second line because the first one shows the order of the variable i.e. cookies then cps etc.

cookies = data[0]
cps = data[1]
auto_clicker_num = data[2]

print(f'Cookies: {cookies}')
print(f'CPS: {cps}')
print(f'Num of auto clickers: {auto_clicker_num}')
```

Returns this:

```
cookies: [
CPS: '
Num of auto clickers: 1
```

This is the txt file:

```
Cookies: xx | CPS: xx | auto_clicker_nums: xx |
['100', '1', '1']
```

Help!

Answer (score 0):

One key thing to note is that `data.readlines()` returns a list of strings.

So `data.readlines()[1]` is actually the second line of the file as a string:

```
"['100', '1', '1']"
```

and not the list object you were expecting.

This is the reason `data[0]` gives you the first character of the string i.e. `[`,
`data[1]` gives the second character of the string i.e. `'` and `data[2]` gives the third character of the string i.e. `1`.

If you want to save data into a file, you could store all your data in a dictionary, then write that dict to a file using [json.dump()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump). And when reading, you read from the file back to your dict with [json.load()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load)